# Fibered product of varieties and dimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, dimension-theory-algebra

I am trying to do exercise 3.1.5 in Liu's book which asks the following.

> Let $X,Y$ be algebraic varieties over a field $k$. Show that $\dim(X\times_k Y)=\dim X\, + \dim Y$.

The hint is to use proposition $2.19$ which says that the dimension of an integral algebraic variety is its transcendence degree. While I thought this would be straightforward, once I do the calculation I end up trying to compute the dimension of $\text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_X(X)\otimes_k \mathcal{O}_Y(Y))$ and I'm not sure how to apply the the theorem on the transcendence degree. My intuition is that I need to use Noether normalization, but I don't see how this gives me what I want. Could someone help me clear this up? Also, can I actually use the theorem since it seems to require integrality (which I thought was baked into the definition of algebraic variety, but maybe not). I saw there were other similar questions but none were quite like this one. If I got it wrong please don't hesitate to redirect me to the right question.

Comment: If you're working with transcendence degrees, then you can specialize to the affine case; does this help?

Comment: So this means I can just take a $\text{Spec} A$ in the cover of $X\times_k Y$ and check here. I think my main issue is I don't understand how tensor products and transcendence degree interact. Since localization and tensor products commute, I think it reduces to finding how to determine the transcendence degree of a tensor product?

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right track. Maybe see if you can write down a transcendence basis?